# pass SQLCMD variables to dbDacFx provider with msdeploy

Tags: sql-server, msdeploy, sql-data-tools

I'm currently using msdeploy's dbDacFx provider to deploy a .dacpac to a database. The dacpac expects three SQLCMD variables. The syntax I am using looks like this:

`-setParam:kind=SqlCommandVariable,scope=Database.dacpac,match=foo1,value="foo1 value"`

I've been trying everything I can find but unfortunately there is next to no documentation around this process. The output I am getting from msdeploy says `Missing values for the following SqlCmd variables: foo1 foo2 foo3`.

If anybody can spot what I'm doing wrong that would be fantastic. If anybody knows where to get some documentation that would be fantastic as well. I would gladly accept any answers that say what I should do, but I would love to understand what all of these values are and WHY I'm doing it wrong.

Edit:
At this point it would appear that such an option does not exist for dbDacFx. Our use case for this feature is attempting to deploy the same template database (managed in visual studio sql projects) to 70+ databases, which we would like to do in parallel. dbSqlPackage (besides being deprecated) is not thread safe and does not allow for parallel deployments. dbDacFx overcomes this shortcoming however it cannot (in my experimentation) be passed SqlCmdVariables that reside at the project level, and it cannot use publish profiles like dbSqlPackage can. I'm in contact with a member of the web deploy team and will post any updates if I am able to figure out how to overcome any of these shortcomings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After emailing some Microsoft employees from the MSDeploy team.... it turns out this is not possible at this time, but may be considered for a future release.

Comment: Have you heard any news on this? MSDeploy shows so much promise to meet our DB deployment needs, but after hours chasing a meaningless error message with no apparent logging/diagnostics, I am now thinking it just doesn't support what we want to do. Very frustrating.

Comment: haven't heard any news.... my coworkers and myself took the SqlPackage offering provided by the Sql Server team and wrapped it in a way that it outputs scripts which we cleanse of statements we don't want (in our case, `drop user .*?;`. After that, we execute the script with SQLCMD again wrapped in the same tool. It turned out to be the fastest deployment option for our purposes.